# How to return values from two tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I need to write SQL query that returns the value (units × price) of each stock that each client holds.

I tried this query but seems not correct.

```
SELECT sc.StockCode,
       SUM(TRY_CAST(sc.Units AS int) * TRY_CAST(sp.PriceNZD AS decimal(18, 2))) AS Value
FROM StockPrice sp
     INNER JOIN StockHoldings sc ON sp.StockCode = sc.StockCode
GROUP BY sc.StockCode
ORDER BY Value DESC;
```

[image]

Comment: Using duplicate accounts is frowned upon, [@Knowledgebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56557766/how-to-write-a-script-that-inserts-records-into-the-database-that-reflect-the-ch). Especially if you're trying to avoid penalties incurred on your other login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be aggregating by stock code *and* client:

```
SELECT
    sc.ClientID,
    sc.StockCode,
    SUM(sc.Units * sp.PriceNZD) AS Value
FROM StockPrice sp
INNER JOIN StockHoldings sc
    ON sp.StockCode = sc.StockCode
GROUP BY
    sc.ClientID,
    sc.StockCode
ORDER BY
    Value DESC;
```

Given that both the `StockHoldings.Units` and `StockPrice.PriceNZD` columns appear to be numeric, I don't see any reason to use `TRY_CAST` here.  If one/both of these columns are text, then I would suggest first converting these columns to numeric before proceeding.

Comment: `Units` is `int` and `PriceNZD` is `decimal(18,2)`. But I need to include `StockCode` as well here.

Comment: That requirement doesn't make much sense, as a given client would generally have _many_ different stock holdings.  Maybe you should show us what your expected output is.

Comment: What I mean is that, I need to sum `units*priceNZD` based on `clientID` and `Stockcode`. It means that ClientID `FNZ01` has 2 `stockcode` and each stock code has `units` and `priceNZD`.

Comment: Try the updated query which now aggregates by both client and stock code.